# Android MediaMuxer Attaching Surface to Codec input

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec, muxer

Okay I've reviewed [Fadden's example](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) of implementing Android MediaMux.  I am not sure how to get my scene into the surface input for a MP4 muxed codec. I am working on a audio processor which eats up the audio and video I/O so MediaRecord fails, but the MediaMux sounds like a viable solution.

From the codec create an inputSurface:

```
videoInputSurface = codec.createInputSurface();
```

I already have an implemented openGLSurfaceView. I can get the surface from the view simply by calling:

```
myGLSurface = myGLView.getHolder().getSurface();
```

but this doesn't set the surface. It just grabs it. Is there an easy way to get myGLSurface to write to videoInputSurface.

To further complicate things I have a cameraPreview being added to same viewgroup, vg, myGLView is written to:

```
vg.addView(mCameraPreview);
```

And myGLView is set to transparent so that the openGL scene is overlayed ontop of the cameraPreview.

```
myGLView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Is there an easy way to get at the surface element of a vg? To simply put what is being written to the vg frame on the videoInputSurface for the codec?

Thanks,

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to take frames from the camera, draw on top of them with OpenGL, and send the result to a video encoder?  Does this need to appear on-screen as well?  (It might help to re-phrase the question in terms of what you're trying to do, rather than describing what you currently have implemented.)

Comment: Yes that is correct, take frames from camera, draw on top via OpenGL, and send to video encoder ... and obviously needs to be previewed or displayed. I could write about what I am trying to do, but I am sure that would muck it up more, so sticking to the basics.

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at [this](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/). The first [example](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/EncodeAndMuxTest.java.txt) shows how to draw by OpenGL ES commands on codec input surface to record it by MediaMuxer to MP4 file.

Comment: Okay so let me see if I have this correct. after I create the codec surface, I use it to create an eglsurface within my openGL stuff, and then simply swap buffers everytime I want what I was drawing to be rendered to the codec? Will this pick up my cameraPreview or will I need to push that to a openGL texture?

Comment: When you look at example you can see the _testEncodeVideoToMp4_ function. If you have Open GL renderer, you need execute commands from _onSurfaceCreated_ and _onSurfaceChanged_ before main _for_ loop and commands from onDrawFrame move to _generateSurfaceFrame_ function.